# Jsp Img tag Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: java, html, spring, jsp

I am new to Jsp, I am using Spring MVC and trying to display logo in my jsp page but I am getting error like this

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

### My jsp looks likes this

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="s"%>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color: wheat;">
        <div align="center">
            <s:form commandName="salarySlipCommandName">
                <img src="/images/logo.png" />
            </s:form>   
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I tried by removing "/" like this `<img src="images/logo.png" />` but unable to solve the issue. unable to get what to do can any one please help me in this regard..?

Comment: Hi Nithin, please add your folder structure. As the error says, it cannot find the image in the specific place.

Answer (score 0):

in jsp use ::

```
<c:forEach items="${images}" var="img">
   <img src="showimage?path=${img}" width="100%" height="auto"/>
</c:forEach>
```

in java code ::

```
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        @RequestMapping(value="/showimage",method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public @ResponseBody void showImage(@RequestParam String path,HttpServletResponse response,HttpServletRequest request){
            //Get project location
            String paaath = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("\\");
            paaath = paaath.substring(0, paaath.length()-1);
            paaath = paaath.substring(0, paaath.lastIndexOf("\\"));
            String loc  = paaath+File.separator+"Projectfolder-DOCS"+File.separator+"images";
             try{
             FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(loc+File.separator+path));
             BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);  
             response.setContentType("image/gif");
             BufferedOutputStream output = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
             for (int data; (data = bis.read()) > -1;) {
               output.write(data);
             }   
             }catch(Exception e){

             }
        }
```

In web apps load images only from project folder make sure you had all of them you need in right place ....

Hope this code will help...

Comment: ${image} is response attribute will be sent when you are redirecting from a page to current image display page...